# Как мне вывести свою подпись для каждой картинки?

Tags: java, android

Есть галерея.

```
public class ImageGridFragment2 extends Fragment {
        protected AbsListView listView;

        public static final int INDEX = 1;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fr_image_grid2, container, false);
            listView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid);
            ((GridView) listView).setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    startImagePagerActivity(position);
                }
            });
            return rootView;
        }

        private void startImagePagerActivity(int position) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SimpleImageActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(Constants.Extra.FRAGMENT_INDEX, ImagePagerFragment.INDEX);
            intent.putExtra(Constants.Extra.IMAGE_POSITION, position);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

            private String[] IMAGE_URLS = Constants.IMAGES;

            private LayoutInflater inflater;

            private DisplayImageOptions options;

            ImageAdapter(Context context) {
                inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

                options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                        .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_stub)
                        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
                        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
                        .cacheInMemory(true)
                        .cacheOnDisk(true)
                        .considerExifParams(true)
                        .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                        .build();
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return IMAGE_URLS.length;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                final ViewHolder holder;
                View view = convertView;
                if (view == null) {
                    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_grid_image, parent, false);
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    assert view != null;
                    holder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
                    holder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
                    holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress);
                    view.setTag(holder);
                } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
                }

                holder.text.setText("Item " + (position + 1));

                ImageLoader.getInstance()
                        .displayImage(IMAGE_URLS[position], holder.imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                                holder.progressBar.setProgress(0);
                                holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                                holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                                holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        }, new ImageLoadingProgressListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onProgressUpdate(String imageUri, View view, int current, int total) {
                                holder.progressBar.setProgress(Math.round(100.0f * current / total));
                            }
                        });

                return view;
            }
        }

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView text;
            ImageView imageView;
            ProgressBar progressBar;
        }
    }
```

item_grid_image.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

В итоге получается картинка и к ней подпись Item(какой-то там).
Как мне вместо Item вывести свою надпись для каждой фотки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все, разобрался. Было проще чем я думал. Добавил список с подписями.
`public String[] title = new String[] {"Подпись 1", "Подпись 2", "Подпись 3", ... и так далее}`
ну и сделал вывод `holder.text.setText(title[position]);`

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что строку

```
holder.text.setText("Item " + (position + 1));
```

Нужно заменить на

```
holder.text.setText("свой текст");
```

Comment: Оеее... Галерея, похоже скаченая из интернета(или хуже) и такой вопрос "Item(какой-то там). Как мне вместо Item вывести свою надпись для каждой фотки?" и "  holder.text.setText("Item " + (position + 1));" оу....

Comment: Галерея из примера Android-Universal-Image-Loader.  holder.text.setText("свой текст"); выводит один и тот же текст под всеми картинками, а мне нужно под каждой картинкой своя подпись.